# How can i iterate and order nested list as a dictionary value in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested-lists

I have a dictionary like this:

```
dict =  {'x': [(['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['e'], ['f'])],'y': [(['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['e'], ['f'])]}
```

I want to iterate over nested lists and add a number to list. The result should be like the below dictionary:

```
res = {'x': [(['a',1], ['b',2], ['c',3], ['d',4], ['e',5], ['f',6])]}
```

How can i add numbers in the nested list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> dct =  {'x': [(['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['e'], ['f'])]}
>>> {k:[tuple([c for c in l]+[i+1] for i,l in enumerate(t)) for t in v ] for k,v in dct.items()}
{'x': [(['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3], ['d', 4], ['e', 5], ['f', 6])]}
```

Answer (score 2):

This does what you want:

```
_dict =  {'x': [(['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['e'], ['f'])],'y': [(['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['e'], ['f'])]}
for item in _dict:
    for index, _list in enumerate(_dict[item][0]):
        _list.append(index + 1)

print(_dict)
# {'x': [(['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3], ['d', 4], ['e', 5], ['f', 6])], 'y': [(['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3], ['d', 4], ['e', 5], ['f', 6])]}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. But I have many key values like this. Can i iterate over all keys and values?

Comment: Instead of specifically updating `_dict['x']`, you would add an outer loop to iterate over the `.values()` of the `_dict`.